# Installing and uninstalling gnome on debian

Tags: debian, gnome

I am using debian sid with xfce.

I would like to test last version of gnome (I didn't give gnome 3.x a chance).

Therfore, I would like to install gnome *but*, also, to know how to go back to my xfce desktop. My worries are to have hard time to uninstall all packages installed for gnome.

I plan to install gnome with :

```
apt-get install gnome
```

Which produces:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  accountsservice aglfn aisleriot alacarte apg argyll bluez bogofilter bogofilter-bdb
  bogofilter-common browser-plugin-gnash caribou caribou-antler cheese cheese-common cli-common
  cracklib-runtime dconf-cli dconf-editor dconf-tools empathy empathy-common eog espeak-data
  evince evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-plugins file-roller finger five-or-more folks-common four-in-a-row gdebi gdm3 gedit
  gedit-common gedit-plugins geoclue geoclue-hostip geoclue-localnet geoclue-manual
  geoclue-nominatim gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm3 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0
  gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-tracker-0.16
  gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0
  gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gksu gnash gnash-common gnome-applets gnome-applets-data
  gnome-backgrounds gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-chess gnome-color-manager
  gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-core gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-dictionary gnome-disk-utility gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-games
  gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-klotski gnome-mag gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-menus
  gnome-mines gnome-nettool gnome-nibbles gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-packagekit
  gnome-packagekit-data gnome-packagekit-session gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager
  gnome-robots gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-session-flashback gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi gnome-system-log
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-tetravex gnome-tweak-tool
  gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-video-effects gnuchess gnuchess-book gnuplot gnuplot-nox
  gnustep-base-common gnustep-base-runtime gnustep-common grilo-plugins-0.2 groff
  gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-nice
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gtk2-engines gucharmap guile-2.0-libs hamster-applet hwdata iagno
  iputils-tracepath libaccountsservice0 libapache2-mod-dnssd libatk-adaptor libatspi1.0-0
  libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavresample1 libboost-chrono1.54.0
  libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libbrlapi0.6 libcamel-1.2-43
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-pulse libcaribou-common
  libcaribou-gtk-module libcaribou-gtk3-module libcaribou0 libchamplain-0.12-0
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcolorblind0 libcolord-gtk1 libcpufreq0 libcrack2 libdbus-glib2.0-cil libdbus2.0-cil
  libdee-1.0-4 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0 libebackend-1.2-6 libebook-1.2-14
  libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-17 libedata-cal-1.2-20
  libedataserver-1.2-17 libespeak1 libevolution libexempi3 libfarstream-0.1-0 libfarstream-0.2-2
  libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgail-common libgconf2.0-cil libgdata-common
  libgdata13 libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common libgdiplus libgdm1 libgeocode-glib0 libgksu2-0
  libgles2-mesa libglib2.0-cil libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome-mag2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgnustep-base1.22 libgrilo-0.2-1
  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgssdp-1.0-3 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-vnc-2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-cil libgtkglext1 libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0
  libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgvnc-1.0-0 libgweather-3-3 libgweather-common
  libibus-1.0-5 libicc2 libidl0 libimdi0 libiptcdata0 libjemalloc1 liblinear-tools liblinear1
  liblouis-data liblouis2 libmeanwhile1 libmetacity-private0a libmission-control-plugins0
  libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil
  libmono-corlib4.5-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil
  libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
  libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmpg123-0 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmutter0b
  libnatpmp1 libnice10 liboauth0 libobjc4 libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4
  libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4
  libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4
  libopencv-video2.4 libopenobex1 liborbit2 libpam-systemd libpanel-applet-4-0 libpst4
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp libpurple-bin libpurple0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libreoffice-gnome librest-extras-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core8 librygel-core-2.0-1
  librygel-renderer-2.0-1 librygel-renderer-gst-2.0-1 librygel-server-2.0-1 libsbc1
  libsocialweb-client2 libsocialweb-common libsocialweb-service libsocialweb0
  libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 libsofia-sip-ua0 libsonic0 libsrtp0 libsvm-tools libsystemd-daemon0
  libtbb2 libtelepathy-farstream3 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger3 libtotem0
  libtracker-extract-0.16-0 libtracker-miner-0.16-0 libwacom-common libwacom2
  libwebrtc-audio-processing-0 libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libytnef0 libzapojit-0.0-0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 libzephyr4 lightsoff media-player-info metacity
  metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mousetweaks mutter-common nautilus
  nautilus-data nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nmap obex-data-server obexd-client
  pidgin-data pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-brlapi python-gconf
  python-gnome2 python-louis python-mako python-markupsafe python-pyatspi python-pyatspi2
  python-pyorbit python-speechd python-wnck python-zeitgeist quadrapassel rdesktop rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins rtkit rygel rygel-playbin
  rygel-preferences simple-scan sound-juicer sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher sudo
  swell-foop systemd tali telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-logger
  telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-rakia telepathy-salut tomboy totem totem-common
  totem-plugins tracker tracker-extract tracker-gui tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils
  transmission-common transmission-gtk unar unoconv vinagre vino xbrlapi xdg-user-dirs-gtk
  xserver-xephyr xul-ext-adblock-plus zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity
  zenity-common
Suggested packages:
  gnome-cards-data gir1.2-colordgtk-1.0 doc-base browser-plugin-lightspark
  gnome-video-effects-frei0r evolution-ews evolution-plugins-experimental
  evolution-data-server-dbg arj lha lzip lzop ncompress rpm2cpio rzip sharutils unace unalz zoo
  dia-gnome gnome-boxes gnucash libreoffice-evolution planner iceweasel-l10n-all
  xul-ext-gnome-keyring libcanberra-gtk3-module gnome-hearts gnome-system-tools
  gnome-packagekit-tools xboard eboard scid feedgnuplot gnuplot-doc libgnuplot-iostream-dev
  python-gnuplot gnustep-base-doc frei0r-plugins python-evolution monodoc-gtk2.0-manual
  liblinear-dev libmono-i18n4.0-all libgamin0 natpmp-utils sofia-sip-doc srtp-utils pidgin gajim
  pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs python-gnome2-doc python-beaker python-mako-doc pcscd
  gnome-codec-install rygel-tracker rygel-mediathek gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-lame
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-really-bad speech-dispatcher-festival speech-dispatcher-doc-cs
  libttspico-utils systemd-ui tasque totem-mozilla gromit
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  evince-gtk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  accountsservice aglfn aisleriot alacarte apg argyll bluez bogofilter bogofilter-bdb
  bogofilter-common browser-plugin-gnash caribou caribou-antler cheese cheese-common cli-common
  cracklib-runtime dconf-cli dconf-editor dconf-tools empathy empathy-common eog espeak-data
  evince evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
  evolution-plugins file-roller finger five-or-more folks-common four-in-a-row gdebi gdm3 gedit
  gedit-common gedit-plugins geoclue geoclue-hostip geoclue-localnet geoclue-manual
  geoclue-nominatim gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm3 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0
  gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-tracker-0.16
  gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0
  gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gksu gnash gnash-common gnome gnome-applets gnome-applets-data
  gnome-backgrounds gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-chess gnome-color-manager
  gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-core gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-dictionary gnome-disk-utility gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-games
  gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-klotski gnome-mag gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-menus
  gnome-mines gnome-nettool gnome-nibbles gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-packagekit
  gnome-packagekit-data gnome-packagekit-session gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager
  gnome-robots gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-session-flashback gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi gnome-system-log
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-tetravex gnome-tweak-tool
  gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-video-effects gnuchess gnuchess-book gnuplot gnuplot-nox
  gnustep-base-common gnustep-base-runtime gnustep-common grilo-plugins-0.2 groff
  gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-nice
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gtk2-engines gucharmap guile-2.0-libs hamster-applet hwdata iagno
  iputils-tracepath libaccountsservice0 libapache2-mod-dnssd libatk-adaptor libatspi1.0-0
  libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavresample1 libboost-chrono1.54.0
  libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-thread1.54.0 libbrlapi0.6 libcamel-1.2-43
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-pulse libcaribou-common
  libcaribou-gtk-module libcaribou-gtk3-module libcaribou0 libchamplain-0.12-0
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcolorblind0 libcolord-gtk1 libcpufreq0 libcrack2 libdbus-glib2.0-cil libdbus2.0-cil
  libdee-1.0-4 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0 libebackend-1.2-6 libebook-1.2-14
  libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-17 libedata-cal-1.2-20
  libedataserver-1.2-17 libespeak1 libevolution libexempi3 libfarstream-0.1-0 libfarstream-0.2-2
  libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgail-common libgconf2.0-cil libgdata-common
  libgdata13 libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common libgdiplus libgdm1 libgeocode-glib0 libgksu2-0
  libgles2-mesa libglib2.0-cil libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome-mag2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgnustep-base1.22 libgrilo-0.2-1
  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgssdp-1.0-3 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-vnc-2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-cil libgtkglext1 libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0
  libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-av-1.0-2
  libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgvnc-1.0-0 libgweather-3-3 libgweather-common
  libibus-1.0-5 libicc2 libidl0 libimdi0 libiptcdata0 libjemalloc1 liblinear-tools liblinear1
  liblouis-data liblouis2 libmeanwhile1 libmetacity-private0a libmission-control-plugins0
  libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil
  libmono-corlib4.5-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil
  libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
  libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmpg123-0 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmutter0b
  libnatpmp1 libnice10 liboauth0 libobjc4 libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4
  libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4
  libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4
  libopencv-video2.4 libopenobex1 liborbit2 libpam-systemd libpanel-applet-4-0 libpst4
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp libpurple-bin libpurple0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libreoffice-gnome librest-extras-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core8 librygel-core-2.0-1
  librygel-renderer-2.0-1 librygel-renderer-gst-2.0-1 librygel-server-2.0-1 libsbc1
  libsocialweb-client2 libsocialweb-common libsocialweb-service libsocialweb0
  libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 libsofia-sip-ua0 libsonic0 libsrtp0 libsvm-tools libsystemd-daemon0
  libtbb2 libtelepathy-farstream3 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger3 libtotem0
  libtracker-extract-0.16-0 libtracker-miner-0.16-0 libwacom-common libwacom2
  libwebrtc-audio-processing-0 libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libytnef0 libzapojit-0.0-0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 libzephyr4 lightsoff media-player-info metacity
  metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mousetweaks mutter-common nautilus
  nautilus-data nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy nmap obex-data-server obexd-client
  pidgin-data pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-brlapi python-gconf
  python-gnome2 python-louis python-mako python-markupsafe python-pyatspi python-pyatspi2
  python-pyorbit python-speechd python-wnck python-zeitgeist quadrapassel rdesktop rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins rtkit rygel rygel-playbin
  rygel-preferences simple-scan sound-juicer sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher sudo
  swell-foop systemd tali telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-idle telepathy-logger
  telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-rakia telepathy-salut tomboy totem totem-common
  totem-plugins tracker tracker-extract tracker-gui tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils
  transmission-common transmission-gtk unar unoconv vinagre vino xbrlapi xdg-user-dirs-gtk
  xserver-xephyr xul-ext-adblock-plus zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub zenity
  zenity-common
0 upgraded, 432 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/259 MB of archives.
After this operation, 891 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

So there are lots of packages...

I would like to be sure to be able to uninstall all these packages after trying gnome for some time. I'm afraid `apt-get remove --purge gnome` will not remove all previously installed packages (because gnome is a meta-package).

So, what should I do, after installing gnome, to go back on my minimal xfce system (i.e. delete all installed gnome related packages)?

Update : `apt-get autoremove` does not remove any of the package installed automatically by gnome.

I deleted the gnome meta-package:

```
 # apt-get remove gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 53.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

And then tried to remove all gnome packages with `autoremove`

```
# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` removes the packages since they were automatically installed and no previously installed package depends on them. In any case you can just copy-paste the list into a file. Then you know if there are any leftovers.

Comment: From the [Debian FAQ](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-datapackages): *“[…] it will not get automatically removed by most package management tools.”* However, the suggested solution using `aptitude` also doesn't remove all packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
aptitude purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep gnome | cut -f 1`
aptitude -f install
aptitude purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f 1`
aptitude -f install
```

Comment: these need to be run as root no?

Comment: this removes a LOT of unrelated stuff.  `caja-gksu`, `evince`, `mate-applets`, `meld`, `pidgin`, `ubuntu-docs`, `x2gomatebindings`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tasksel`.

It will open a menu where you can install/uninstall gnome, xfce, others GUI and other things.
Use tab or the arrow keys to move and the space bar to select/unselct.
[image]

(Install it if for some reason you do not have it: `apt install tasksel`).

Comment: This only removes the `task-gnome-desktop` package.